# SQL Server DATE filtering/comparison SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

Please explain why I am getting the error :

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Error converting a string to a date and / or time.

For this T-SQL query:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM project p 
WHERE p.dueDate BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-31'
```

I also already tried casting the column to a `Date`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM [ffflow_dev].[dbo].[project] as p 
WHERE CAST(p.dueDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-31'
```

Thanks anyone that will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

February only has 28 days, and 29 days in a leap year.  So the date literal `2018-02-31` is invalid, and the error message from SQL Server is telling you that it can't convert this literal into an actual date.  If you want to cover the entire month of February 2018, then use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM project
WHERE dueDate >= '2018-02-01' AND dueDate < '2018-03-01';
```

The advantage of the above logic is that it actually frees you from even having to know how many days are actually in February for 2018.  Instead, you just restrict on the right side to anything less than March 1st at midnight, which falls back to the entire month of February.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. My query works now.